# How to log SOAP messages of BPEL process in Apache ODE

Tags: tomcat, soap, bpel, apache-ode

I'm running a simple BPEL process using Apache ODE 1.3.7 (deployed in Tomcat v9.0.0) that invokes an external SOAP web service and i wanna log the SOAP messages that are been sended.

I found in other stackoverflow question (old question) a recomendation to enable [this line](https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/trunk/axis2-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/ode-axis2.properties#L95) in **ode-axis2.properties** file.

`#ode-axis2.event.listeners=org.apache.ode.bpel.common.evt.DebugBpelEventListener`

With this right now i'm able to see the response of partners links in **ode.log** file but im unable to see the SOAP requests messages.

Anybody knows another way to achieve that or what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using ODE 1.3.7

Add these loggers to log4j2.xml

```
<Logger name="httpclient.wire.content" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="httpclient.wire.header" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
</Logger>
```

FYI, ode-axis2.event.listeners are used to subscribe to events generated by the engine. Remember that it generated tremendous amount of events which helps for debugging processes.

ode-axis2.event.listeners=org.apache.ode.bpel.common.evt.DebugBpelEventListener

Comment: Thank you this works! Where did you find this configuration?

Comment: Axis2 is used as the integration layer in ODE which in turn uses httpclient.
http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html